# How can I refer to data assets from a module?

Tags: python, module

I am building a Python module that uses an asset file (a JSON file in this case), which is stored in the modules directory:

```
root
 +--- mymodule
         +------ __init__.py
         +------ mymodule.py
         +------ myasset.json
```

But, when I `open` this as

```
with open("myasset.json", "r") as assetfile:
     ....
```

it cannot find it, because the working directory is something else.

How should I refer to an asset file from within my module?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python >= 3.9 then `importlib.resources.files(__package__)` should work, per [Python 3 importlib.resources docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.resources.html#importlib.resources.files)

Given the OP structure, this should work:

```py
    import importlib.resources

    MODULE_PATH = importlib.resources.files(__package__)

    asset_file_data = (MODULE_PATH / "myasset.json").read_text()
```

I haven't had a chance to do much testing for edge cases, but this works on python 2.7 through 3.10:

```py
import os.path

MODULE_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

with open(os.path.join(MODULE_PATH, "myasset.json"), 'r') as asset_file:
  asset_file_data = asset_file.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which file you are running.

If you run `main.py` in the `root`, you can get access to paths with:

```
# mymodule/mymodule.py

# path of this file file
print(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print(__file__)

# path of this folder
print(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
print(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent)

# main.py folder
print(pathlib.Path().resolve())
print(os.getcwd())

# python paths list
print(sys.path)
```

**In your case:**

```
from pathlib import Path

with open(Path(__file__).parent.joinpath("myasset.json"), "r") as assetfile:
    ....
```